# How to use or activate SSL in AKS POD, IP or Domain

Tags: azure, kubernetes, .net-core

how to activate SSL or have the route to my microservice have HTTPS in the URL, I have tried with `CERT-MANAGER` but nothing, or how to modify my `deployment.yml` file

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ms-app-deployment
  labels:
    app: ms-app-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ms-app-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ms-app-deployment
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: ms-app-deployment
          secret:
            secretName: tls-secret
      containers:
        - name: ms-app
          image: qa.azurecr.io/ms-app:1.00
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "512Mi"
              cpu: "1"
            requests:
              memory: "256Mi"
              cpu: "0.5"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          env:
            - name: VERSION
              value: "1.00"
            - name: SECRET_KEY
              value: ""
            - name: TOKEN_EXPIRATION
              value: "60"
            - name: PORT
              value: "3000"

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ms-app-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: ms-app-deployment
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Expecting add code, file, change config, etc, any custom, create a service, etc

I created secret, but nothing

I created `cert-manager`
I Created `cert-manager-webhook`

Comment: Most documentation is related to aplying SSL at the Ingress level. But for your scenario I think that you could follow this https://cert-manager.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started-aks-letsencrypt/

Answer (score 0):

To use SSL in AKS, you can use Cert Manager to obtain and manage SSL certificates for Kubernetes deployments, [Hackerman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1987838/hackerman) has shared an excellent [document](https://cert-manager.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started-aks-letsencrypt/) in comment section. Follow the document and

1. Install Cert Manager on your AKS cluster using the Helm chart. You can follow the steps in the context URLs provided to install Cert Manager.

```
helm repo add jetstack https://charts.jetstack.io
helm repo update
helm upgrade cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager \
    --install \
    --create-namespace \
    --wait \
    --namespace cert-manager \
    --set installCRDs=true
```

[image]

2. Create a  `ClusterIssuer`  resource to represent the Let's Encrypt certificate authority where the signed certificate is obtained. You can follow the steps in the context URLs provided to create a  `ClusterIssuer`  resource.

```yaml
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-staging
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: $EMAIL_ADDRESS
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-staging
    solvers:
    - dns01:
        azureDNS:
          resourceGroupName: $AZURE_DEFAULTS_GROUP
          subscriptionID: $AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
          hostedZoneName: $DOMAIN_NAME
          environment: AzurePublicCloud
          managedIdentity:
            clientID: $USER_ASSIGNED_IDENTITY_CLIENT_ID
```

If self-signed then

```yaml
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: selfsigned
spec:
  selfSigned: {}
```

3. update the certificate obtained by Cert Manager.
   [image]
4. Modify your deployment YAML file to use the SSL/TLS secret.
   Deployment-

```yaml
# deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: helloweb
  labels:
    app: hello
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello
      tier: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello
        tier: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-app
        image: <image_path>
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8443
        volumeMounts:
          - name: tls
            mountPath: /etc/tls
            readOnly: true
        env:
          - name: TLS_CERT
            value: /etc/tls/tls.crt
          - name: TLS_KEY
            value: /etc/tls/tls.key
      volumes:
      - name: tls
        secret:
          secretName: www-tls
```

Update your service YAML file to use HTTPS. Change the `port`
service-

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: helloweb
    annotations:
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-dns-label-name: $AZURE_LOADBALANCER_DNS_LABEL_NAME
spec:
    ports:
    - port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8443
    selector:
        app: hello
        tier: web
    type: LoadBalancer
```

[image]

5. Redeploy your application with the updated YAML files.

[image]

After following these steps, your microservice should be accessible via HTTPS.

References:

- [Use certificates with LetsEncrypt.org on Application Gateway for AKS clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-letsencrypt-certificate-application-gateway)
- [Quickstart: Deploy a Scalable & Secure WordPress instance on AKS - Set Up Cert Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/linux-workloads/createwordpressdeployment/readme#set-up-cert-manager)
- [Quickstart: Deploy a Scalable & Secure Azure Kubernetes Service cluster using the Azure CLI - Set Up Cert Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/linux-workloads/createaksdeployment/readme#set-up-cert-manager)